# UITableViewCell on left swipe doesn't trigger editActionsForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uitapgesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a scrollview which contains different subviews, one of which is tableview. I also have a `UITapGestureRecognizer` and `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` initialized on the scroll view. The tableview uses a nib to initialize its cell.

What I would like to do is that, when I swipe the cell to the left, I want a button to swipe in. I am able to trigger my handler when left swipe the cell. The problem is that it doesn't trigger the `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath` where I am handling the code to create a button.

Instead, it goes to `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` and ends executing showing a red icon with a minus sign to the left of the cell.

My swipe handler and related code is as below:

```
- (void)swipeLeftDirection:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
    if (!tblInviteesTable.editing)
    {
        CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView: tblInviteesTable];
        iPath = [tblInviteesTable indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
       // quitEditing = NO;

        OpenHouseTableViewCell *currentCell = (OpenHouseTableViewCell *)[self tableView:tblInviteesTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:iPath];
        [currentCell setEditing:YES];

        [tblInviteesTable setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        [self tableView:tblInviteesTable editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:iPath];
    }}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return YES;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        NSLog(@"Handled editing style! %ld", (long)editingStyle);


    } else {
        NSLog(@"Unhandled editing style! %ld", (long)editingStyle);
    }
}
-(NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if ([tableView isEqual: tblInviteesTable]){
    UITableViewRowAction *button = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Resend" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath) {
        NSLog(@"Resending email");
       // [_delegate listingAgentsView: self selected: indexPath];

    }];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    return @[button];
}
return @[];
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.